# How to bind AtlGr to Ctrl+Alt in Debian 7

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I recently I installed Debian 7 in my laptop.  I used to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcut all the time in Windows, but in Debian 7 I can only use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

So, I was trying to bind <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> without success. First I installed AutoKey but then I didn't know how to use it. Then I installed xbindkeys and tried doing some configuration to get the binding but it didn't work. And I tried more and more things...

At this point I don't know what to do.

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> makes me work slowly. There is any way to do the binding without getting head cancer?

Comment: Well I must be missing something. I put in my `~/.xbindkeysrc` `"xdotool key Ctrl+Alt"` `Alt+Mod2 + Alt_R`and it does not work. If you find a solution, please post it. :)

Comment: I already solved it. The problem was that I didn know how to use xbindkeys because I'm a linux noob but I finally got it. I added some commands to`xbindkeysrc` like you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I learned how to use xbindkeys. I only had to add the following commands to the `xbindkeysrc` file placed in my personal folder:

```
# LeftBracket
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "[""
  Control+Alt + dead_grave | m:0xc + c:34

# RightBracket
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "]""
  Control+Alt + plus | m:0xc + c:35

# LeftKey
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "{""
  Control+Alt + dead_acute | m:0xc + c:48

# RightKey
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "}""
  Control+Alt + ccedilla | m:0xc + c:51

# Pipe
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "|""
  Control+Alt+Mod2 + 1 | m:0x1c + c:10

# AtSign
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "@""
  Control+Alt+Mod2 + 2 | m:0x1c + c:11

# Hash
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "#""
  Control+Alt+Mod2 + 3 | m:0x1c + c:12

# Virgulilla (Spanish keyboard)
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "~""
  Control+Alt+Mod2 + 4 | m:0x1c + c:13

# Slash
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\""
  Control+Alt+Mod2 + masculine | m:0x1c + c:49
```

After that I added xbindkeys to `gnome-session-properties` to run xbindkeys at startup.
This way I can use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> like I used to.